# Print repeated lines of strings based on values in another file

Tags: bash, unix, awk, printf

I'm sure there's an awk solution to this, but I've been fumbling with it for far too long. I'm trying to print repeats of a string from one file, based on the corresponding line value from another file. For example:

**file1.txt**

```
Hello
Beautiful
World
```

**file2.txt**

```
2
4
3
```

**desired_output_file.txt**

```
Hello
Hello
Beautiful
Beautiful
Beautiful
Beautiful
World
World
World
```

Comment: What did you try for yourself? Post your research efforts

Comment: The approach I would take is to cat the two files together using the paste -d command. That gets you a line like "2,Hello" which would be easier to process in awk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another `awk`

```
$ paste file1 file2 | awk '{while($2--) print $1}'

Hello
Hello
Beautiful
Beautiful
Beautiful
Beautiful
World
World
World
```

Comment: How about `A sentence with spaces` in file1?

Comment: Obviously this form not going to work.  In that case `paste` with a  delimiter and use the same delimiter in `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0; next} {for (i=1; i<=$1; i++) print a[FNR]}' file1 file2
```

```
Hello
Hello
Beautiful
Beautiful
Beautiful
Beautiful
World
World
World
```

---

**References:**

- [Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)
- [Awk Tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)